# Java micro service distributed tracing with Istio

Tags: istio, spring-cloud-sleuth

Kubernetes and Istio already installed in the cluster. Three micro services deployed as PODs. The flow is

```
Micro service A to Micro Service B calls => HTTP
Micro service B to Micro service C calls => via Kafka
Micro service A expose a HTTP API to outside
```

I guess when client hit the Ingres, Istio generate traceId and spanId in HTTP header and enter to Service A. 
Are these spanId and traceId propagate to Micro service B and C without using separate API like Spring Cloud sleuth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Istio does not provide tracing headers propagation. However it can be configured on application side without use of 3rd party APIs.

According to [Istio](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/) documentation:

> Istio leverages  [Envoy’s distributed tracing](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.12.0/intro/arch_overview/observability/tracing)  feature to provide tracing integration out of the box. Specifically, Istio provides options to install various tracing backend and configure proxies to send trace spans to them automatically. See  [Zipkin](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/zipkin/),  [Jaeger](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/jaeger/)  and  [LightStep](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/lightstep/)  task docs about how Istio works with those tracing systems.

---

Istio documentation also has an [example](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/#trace-context-propagation) of application side header propagation for the bookinfo demo application:

> ### Trace context propagation
>
> Although Istio proxies are able to automatically send spans, they need some hints to tie together the entire trace. Applications need to propagate the appropriate HTTP headers so that when the proxies send span information, the spans can be correlated correctly into a single trace.
>
> To do this, an application needs to collect and propagate the following headers from the incoming request to any outgoing requests:
>
> - `x-request-id`
> - `x-b3-traceid`
> - `x-b3-spanid`
> - `x-b3-parentspanid`
> - `x-b3-sampled`
> - `x-b3-flags`
> - `x-ot-span-context`
>
> Additionally, tracing integrations based on  [OpenCensus](https://opencensus.io/)  (e.g. Stackdriver) propagate the following headers:
>
> - `x-cloud-trace-context`
> - `traceparent`
> - `grpc-trace-bin`
>
> If you look at the sample Python  `productpage`  service, for example, you see that the application extracts the required headers from an HTTP request using  [OpenTracing](https://opentracing.io/)  libraries:

```py
def getForwardHeaders(request):
    headers = {}

    # x-b3-*** headers can be populated using the opentracing span
    span = get_current_span()
    carrier = {}
    tracer.inject(
        span_context=span.context,
        format=Format.HTTP_HEADERS,
        carrier=carrier)

    headers.update(carrier)

    # ...

    incoming_headers = ['x-request-id']

    # ...

    for ihdr in incoming_headers:
        val = request.headers.get(ihdr)
        if val is not None:
            headers[ihdr] = val

    return headers
```

> The reviews application (Java) does something similar:

```java
@GET
@Path("/reviews/{productId}")
public Response bookReviewsById(@PathParam("productId") int productId,
                            @HeaderParam("end-user") String user,
                            @HeaderParam("x-request-id") String xreq,
                            @HeaderParam("x-b3-traceid") String xtraceid,
                            @HeaderParam("x-b3-spanid") String xspanid,
                            @HeaderParam("x-b3-parentspanid") String xparentspanid,
                            @HeaderParam("x-b3-sampled") String xsampled,
                            @HeaderParam("x-b3-flags") String xflags,
                            @HeaderParam("x-ot-span-context") String xotspan) {

  if (ratings_enabled) {
    JsonObject ratingsResponse = getRatings(Integer.toString(productId), user, xreq, xtraceid, xspanid, xparentspanid, xsampled, xflags, xotspan);
```

> When you make downstream calls in your applications, make sure to include these headers.

Comment: For a Java app can it be done with Spring Cloud sleuth ? Because the way it did it each HTTP call need to modify and different approach has to take for Kafka (Service B to Service C call).

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with Spring Cloud sleuth framework. I was not able to find much about Your tools combination, there is an [ebook](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781789613476/14/ch14lvl1sec112/introducing-distributed-tracing-with-spring-cloud-sleuth-and-zipkin) that has some information about it.